# How to remove the width property from the style attribute?

Tags: php, laravel

I installed the **Kaishiyoku / laravel-html-purifier** package, from the documentation of this package, it is not clear how to add exceptions for the elements.

XSS

```
<p style="width:100000px;height:100000px;
margin-top:-1000px;margin-left:-1000px;background:#000;">test</p>
```

```
$purifier = new HtmlPurifier();

$textComment = $purifier->purify($request->text);
```

Comment: This package doesn't allow any configuration. You can copy it and make changes in source code since it just uses http://htmlpurifier.org with additional set of rules. See here https://github.com/Kaishiyoku/laravel-html-purifier/blob/master/src/Kaishiyoku/HtmlPurifier/HtmlPurifier.php